# Drawing + UITableViewCell + UIScrollView subclass?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

My (rather complicated) situation is as follows:

- `TestView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` which implements `-drawRect:`, but at some point inside `-drawRect:` it'll call a method, let's say `-drawAnotherPartWithRect:context:`. This method is implemented by subclasses of `TestView` to draw individually a certain part of the context.
- There are two subclasses of `TestView` which implement `-drawAnotherPartWithRect:context:`, which currently do the *same thing* inside it: `Subclass1` and `Subclass2`.
- As of now, ***frame size*** is the only different between the two during initialization.

An instance of `Subclass1` is used as a table view's section header, and it works perfectly, yet if `Subclass2` is used as a subview of the cell's content view, it'll display, yet not scroll. Its initialization is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PortoAppSubjectViewTableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PortoAppSubjectViewTableViewCell"] autorelease];

        Subclass2 *contentView = [[[Subclass2 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [tableView bounds].size.width, 32.f)] autorelease];
        [contentView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width * 3, 32.f)];
        [contentView setTag:55];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:contentView];
    }

    [(SubjectTableViewCellContentView *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:55] setContainer:[[[[$container subGradeContainers] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] subGradeContainers] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

The interesting thing is, the horizontal scroll indicator shows up and shows me that it's scrolling finely, yet the text (drawn with CoreText) doesn't move left/right along with it. That works out-of-the-box with `Subclass1`. Additionally, if `Subclass2` is used instead as the view class of the section header view, it'll work finely.

So, what's up with horizontal scroll views and table view cells? I've checked out other related questions on SO but haven't been able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by instead of drawing directly to a `UIScrollView` subclass, drawing to a `UIView` subclass added as a subview of `UIScrollView`.

I'd still like some follow-ups, therefore leaving the question unanswered – why did it work with the header view and not with the table view cell then?